# Custom BsonSerializer for generic value types

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have written a custom Bson serializer attribute.

It works fine when the value passed to the Serialize method is of ValueKind "Object".

But if the ValueKind is of any other datatype like string, int, bool, etc it gives error as "Cannot deserialize a BsonDocument from BsonType String"

How to make it generic to work for all data types and decorate with an attribute.

Model:

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(CustomSerialize))]
[BsonElement("response")]
public object response { get; set; }
```

CustomSerialize class:

```
   public class CustomSerialize : SerializerBase<Object>
    {
        public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
        {
            var element = (JsonElement)value;
            BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(element.GetRawText());
            var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(BsonDocument));
            serializer.Serialize(context, document.AsBsonValue);
        }

        public override object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(BsonDocument));
            var document = serializer.Deserialize(context, args);
            var bsonDocument = document.ToBsonDocument();
            var result = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(bsonDocument);
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) serializer inside:

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test
{
    public class CustomSerialize : SerializerBase<object>
    {
        public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            context.Writer.WriteString(json);
        }

        public override object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context,
            BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var json = context.Reader.ReadString();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
        }
    }
}
```